# Flow charting in enterprise architect 7.x

Tags: flowchart, enterprise-architect

Has anyone noticed when you put a '`Descision`' element in flow chart diagram, why does the text over it always displays with `«FC_Decision»` for example - `'«FC_Decision» Your Text'` ?

Answer (score 2):

The text between the guillemets is the [stereotype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype_%28UML%29) of the element.

You can turn off stereotype display on the diagram by editing the diagram properties (right click on the Diagram element in the Project Browser -> Properties | Elements | Show Element Stereotypes).